# Workflow Timer Interval

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, timer-jobs

Can I change Workflow Timer Interval value from default "every 5 minutes" to "every minutes" without impact to performace?

Thanks for supprt,
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to do this without at least a small impact on performance, and generally this is a bad idea.  It is important to understand that when scheduling your timer jobs, if the previous job is still running it will skip a cycle.  Since the scope of this setting is not just for the one workflow, you have to understand it can have far reaching impact.  As that scheduled job starts taking more resources, it could negatively impact other timer jobs.

Some specific things to consider before making the change include:

- How much content you have in the system
- How many active workflows you have running at any one time
- How many servers you have supporting the farm running the timer service

If you have a particular workflow that requires near real-time processing, then it might be best to take a different approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It was only question and I did it because I have a few workflows which has "wait for duration" or "pause until" actions and they are sending ones a week some reports and every week 5 minutes later and this is not good behavior in those cases... And I am wondering what should I do to avoid these delays?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you say it a different way?

Comment: The problem is that I have wokflows which send files ones a week("wait for duration" action with loop) and every week wokflow start and send files 5 minutethis is s later? The same is when I set action "wait for 5 minutes" and wokflow ones start after 5 minuts and ones after 10 minutes...

Comment: I would analyze the job history and see how long it takes to execute the job today.  It sounds like it may already be running long, and perhaps skipping cycles.

Comment: If yes what can be a reason of of this?

Comment: If there isn't something erroring out that can be fixed, and its just a pure scaling issue, then I would look to add additional ram or CPUs to the farm and/or add another server to the farm that can also run the timerjob service.

Answer (score 1):

Running something five time as often will off course have impact on the performance.

But it is only by measuring the performance prior to,and after, a change in the interval that you will now how much and in what ways. Because how your specific SharePoint installation is what really matters, therefor there is no single answer like "Yes by so and much".